# Interactive-Brokers REST API - POST with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, interactive-brokers

I'm running the REST API in my local machine - Windows 7 - Chrome Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I took care of any Cross Domain issue with a Chrome extension.

The GET is working fine. I have problems with the POST
I included a simple example of what I'm running. I get a 400 (Bad Request) error back.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

(I'm using my paper account)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>IB Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script language="javascript">
        
        $.ajax({
            url:'https://localhost:5000/v1/api/iserver/account/DU4530000/orders',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{
                    orders: [
                                {
                                    acctId: "DU4530000",
                                    conid: 272093,
                                    secType: "STK",
                                    orderType: "LMT",
                                    price: 339.40,
                                    quantity: 1,
                                    side: "BUY",
                                    tif: "DAY"
                                }
                    ]
            },
            success:function(){alert("Sucess!!!!");},
            error:function(){alert("Error!!!!");}
        });
        
    </script>

    
</body>
</html>
```